# Cell Hyperlink in PHP using HTML

Tags: php, html, href

I searched for some answers, but nothing worked. I have an HTML table in my index.php and everything works fine. I now want to add a new `<td>` and want it to be a clickable link.
This is the table now **without the link**:

```
<?php
    $file1 = "c:/tablename.txt";
    $file2 = "c:/tablestatus.txt";
    $file3 = "c:/tablelocation.txt";
    $file4 = "c:/userlist.csv";
    if(file_exists($file1) && file_exists($file2))
    {
        $line1= file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
         $line2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
         $line3raw = file($file3, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
         $line3 = array_map("utf8_encode", $line3raw );
         $line4 = file($file4, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

         $html = '<table align="center">';
             $html .= '<tr><th width="460px"></th><th width="140px"></th><th width="340px"></th></tr>';
                for($i=0;$i<count($line1);$i++){
                    $html .= '<tr class="'.$line2[$i].'">'; 
                        $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line1[$i].'</td>';
                        $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line2[$i].'</td>';
                        $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line3[$i].'</td>';
                        $html .= '</tr>';
                    }
                    $html .= '</table>';
                    echo $html;
                }else
                {
                    echo "Files missing.";
                }
?>
```

I found out how to make a cell as a link like this:

```
<td><a href="https://mypage.com" target="_blank">title</a>;</td>
```

That didn't work.
This works:

```
$html .= '<a href="https://mypage.com\" target="_blank">'.$line1[$i].'</a>';
```

But obviously, it's not part of the table anymore. How can I put this hyperlink into the table?

If you need more information or I missed something, just tell. I hope we can solve this issue.

Comment: you have the answer already then what do u want now

Comment: what do you mean by not a part of a table

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar I didn't have the answer because I didn't know the right syntax for it. Take a look the answer, that was right what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it is:

```
 <?php
        $file1 = "c:/tablename.txt";
        $file2 = "c:/tablestatus.txt";
        $file3 = "c:/tablelocation.txt";
        $file4 = "c:/userlist.csv";
        if(file_exists($file1) && file_exists($file2))
        {
            $line1= file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
             $line2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
             $line3raw = file($file3, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
             $line3 = array_map("utf8_encode", $line3raw );
             $line4 = file($file4, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

             $html = '<table align="center">';
                 $html .= '<tr><th width="460px"></th><th width="140px"></th><th width="340px"></th></tr>';
                    for($i=0;$i<count($line1);$i++){
                        $html .= '<tr class="'.$line2[$i].'">'; 
                            $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt"><a href="https://mypage.com\" target="_blank">'.$line1[$i].'</a></td>';
                            $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line2[$i].'</td>';
                            $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line3[$i].'</td>';
                            $html .= '</tr>';
                        }
                        $html .= '</table>';
                        echo $html;
                    }else
                    {
                        echo "Files missing.";
                    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes! That made it. Thank you.